# How to render another List when rowClick show

Tags: react-admin

I was kind of dropped into a Project that uses react-admin and I am supposed to do the following ....

In `App.js` we have a Ressource `products`. Now I am supposed to add another Ressource `Manufacturers`, specifically for one Manufacturer, e.g. `Example Manufacturer`.

`App.js`

```js
<Resource name="products" list={ProductsList} show={ProductsEdit} />
<Resource name="manufacturers/ExampleManufacturer/products" list={ManufacturerProductsList} />
```

So when I click on the `Resource` it opens the `ManufacturerProductsList` and fetches via `getList` from the API. The Data has the following format (basically)

```js
data = [{id: '2020-01', count: 1}, {id: '2020-02', count: 5}]
```

So for every month it shows a count. Now when I click on a row, I want it to display a List of the selected month! From that List I want to be able to Select Items and use an Action, filter, or open the Product. This is where I am encountering my Problem.

I cannot figure out how to pass the Data to a List that does not end in an error of some kind.

I tried to write a `CustomRoute`, `useListContext`, `RessourceContextProvider` and more ...

My most recent (and most promising) Try is the following.

```js
  const { loading, total, data, error } = useQuery({
    type: 'getList',
    resource: 'manufacturers/ExampleManufacturer/products/2021-02',
    payload: {
      pagination: { page: 1, perPage: 10 },
      sort: { field: 'id', order: 'ASC' },
      filter: {}
    }
  });
  if (loading) return <Loading />
  if (error) return <p>Error: {error}</p>
  return (
    <ResourceContextProvider value="manufacturers">
      <ListContextProvider value={{
        basePath: '/manufacturers',
        data: keyBy(data, 'id'),
        ids: data.map(({ id }) => id),
        currentSort: { field: 'id', order: 'ASC' },
        selectedIds: []
      }}>
        <Datagrid rowClick="show">
          <TextField source="id" />
          <TextField source="type" />
        </Datagrid>
        <Pagination
          page={1}
          perPage={50}
          setPage={(numb) => console.log(numb)}
          total={total}
        />
      </ListContextProvider>
    </ResourceContextProvider>
  );
```

The `data` receives the data and everything, but I get the following hard crash error.

```
Datagrid.js:79 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'field' of undefined
    at Datagrid.js:79
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14803)
    at updateForwardRef (react-dom.development.js:16816)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:18645)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:188)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:237)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:292)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23203)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22154)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:22130)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:21756)
    at react-dom.development.js:11089
    at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:653)
    at runWithPriority$1 (react-dom.development.js:11039)
    at flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl (react-dom.development.js:11084)
    at flushSyncCallbackQueue (react-dom.development.js:11072)
    at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:21199)
    at dispatchAction (react-dom.development.js:15660)
    at hooks.js:13
    at useQuery.js:126
```

Comment: Have you tried using the `expand` prop on your Datagrid https://marmelab.com/react-admin/List.html#expand ?